# Why can I not get the text (name) of this button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner to javascript/jquery and I cannot figure out why I cannot fetch the text of the button clicked. When I `console.log(this)` it returns the button text. I cannot retrieve the value however to pass into the queryURL in the click handler. Sorry for the rudimentary question, any help would be appreciated.

```js
        var topics = ["boardwalk empire", "sopranos", "the wire", "billions", "entourage", "dexter", "breaking bad", "better call saul", "dark", "black mirror",]
        var baseURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q="
        var apiKey = "Yz4pO4lJDaMYGIX80M9gc2Mq7HKKS2or"
        
        for (var e = 0; e < topics.length; e++) {
            var button = $("<button>").text(topics[e]);
            button.addClass("btn-primary");
            $(".show-buttons").append(button);

            button.on("click",function (){
            var input = $(this).val()
            console.log(this)
            var queryURL = baseURL + input + "&api_key=" + apiKey + "&limit=10";
            $.ajax({
                url: queryURL,
                method: "GET"
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(queryURL);
            });
        });

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>gifTastic!</h1>
        <label for="search-field">Find a TV Show: </label>
        <input type="text" id="search-field">
        <input id="find-giphy" class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="giphy Search">
        <div class="show-buttons"></div>
        <div class="show-gifs"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean the value or the button name? You have neither attribute set. Are you trying to get the button text?

Comment: @basic I am trying to get the button text.

Comment: Your buttons do not have names.

Comment: There is only an input tag of type submit, no button.  Where your button at?

Comment: @Herohtar I edited the question for clarification. I just need the text of the button itself.

Comment: @Programnik the buttons are created using jquery and attached to the DOM with the `append` method.

Comment: You are setting the text of the button, but then retrieving the val().  If the text is what you need, retrieve that

Comment: If all you want is the text then you just need `var input = $(this).html()`

Comment: @Herohtar that answers my Q if you want to submit that as an answer. I thought I needed to use .val() to retrieve the text. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify btn click function to:

```
button.on("click",function (){
            var input = $(this).text();   // .text() can be used to set and get text
```